# java regular expression check date format

Tags: java, regex

```
private static String REGEX_ANY_MONTH = "January|Jan|February|Feb|March|Mar|April|Apr|May|June|Jun|"
        + "July|Jul|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec";
private static String REGEX_ANY_YEAR = "[0-9]{4}";
private static String REGEX_ANY_DATE = "[0-9]{1,2}";

private String getFormat(String date) {
    if (date.matches(REGEX_ANY_MONTH + " " + REGEX_ANY_DATE + "," + " " + REGEX_ANY_YEAR)) {
        return "{MONTH} {DAY}, {YEAR}";
    } else if (date.matches(REGEX_ANY_MONTH + " " + REGEX_ANY_YEAR)){
        return "{MONTH} {YEAR}";
    }
    return null;
}


@Test
public void testGetFormatDateString() throws Exception{
    String format = null;
    String test = null;
    test = "March 2012";
    format = Whitebox.<String> invokeMethod(obj, "getFormat", test);
    Assert.assertEquals("{MONTH} {YEAR}", format);

    test = "March 10, 2012";
    format = Whitebox.<String> invokeMethod(obj, "getFormat", test);
    Assert.assertEquals("{MONTH} {DATE}, {YEAR}", format);

}
```

Both of the asserts are failing for me. What am I missing?

Comment: what is the actual value of `format` when the asserts happen?

Comment: the value of format is null when assert happens

Comment: @azurefrog: its a typo. edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your piped list of month names in parentheses in order for it to match.

```
private static String REGEX_ANY_MONTH = "(January|Jan|February|Feb|March|Mar|April|Apr|May|June|Jun|"
    + "July|Jul|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec)";
```

Otherwise the 'or' condition will be or-ing more than just the month.

Comment: Beat me to it, but this! @riship89 - without the parentheses, you were basically matching against any date that was just a month or that began with "Dec". You can even Open the `(` with `(?:` so it creates a non-capturing group, useful for when you edit a regex and don't want to have to change backreferences concerning captured groups.